# Calling PowerShell function from within the script in C# Application

Tags: c#, powershell, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

I just started playing with PowerShell two days ago.  I am running a PowerShell script form a C# console application.  I pass in a list of objects (MyObj1) as a parameter to the script and do some data manipulation to the object. However, when I call a function within the script I get a function not recognized error while printing out the errors.  Here is a small sample of what I am doing.

```
public class MyObj1
{
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
    public int Property2 {get; set;}
}
```

Here is part of code that I am using to run the script:

```
var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
rs.Open();
rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("list", myObjectList);
rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("xml", xml);
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = rs;
var psScript = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\ps.ps1");
ps.AddScript(psScript);
ps.Invoke();
foreach (var item in myObjectList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Property1 + "; " + item.Property1);
}

Console.WriteLine("\n================================ ERRORS ============================ \n");

foreach (ErrorRecord err in ps.Streams.Error)
{
    Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
}
```

And here is the actual script:

```
$list | ForEach {
    $_.Property1 = $_.GetType()
    DoSomeThing ([ref] $_)
}

Function DoSomeThing ($MyObject)
{
    $Asset.Property2 = $Asset.Property2 + $Asset.Property2
}
```

Two days ago while I was playing with same script using some dummy classes like above, I was able to modify the data but since this morning, I have modified the script to use real classes.  And Ctrl+Z will only take me back to a certain point in my editor.  In the `ForEach` loop everything works until I cal the function.

As for the project, the plan is to push this application with required data manipulation in C# and then have some optional changes done in the script. The point is to avoid push to the application to production server and handling all/most data manipulation in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move function declaration to the beginnig of the script file.

```
Function DoSomeThing ($MyObject)
{
    $Asset.Property2 = $Asset.Property2 + $Asset.Property2
}

$list | ForEach {
    $_.Property1 = $_.GetType()
    DoSomeThing ([ref] $_)
}
```

PS doesn't compile script, it executes it command by command. So you have to create/declare function before you use it.

Comment: Makes sense. Will try it in the AM. If I can come up with my old sample again, I will post it here but I still had the function declared after the $list loop.